# ¿Origen del uso de "¡Toma!" para celebrar algo?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, interjecciones

Se usa mucho la palabra *toma* para celebrar algo, pero el [significado de la misma](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=pL8P12BNkDXX2zICEhBV) es muy diferente y no concuerda con el ámbito de celebración.

¿Alguien sabría decirme de dónde viene el uso la expresión *¡Toma!* para celebrar algo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu duda proviene de que has consultado "toma" como sustantivo, cuando en la expresión *¡Toma!* lo que se usa es el imperativo del verbo **[tomar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZzcN8W0)**. Hay varias acepciones del verbo que podrían servirnos, e incluso se recogen algunas expresiones con connotaciones parecidas:

> **tomar**
>
> 3. tr. Recibir algo y hacerse cargo de ello.
> 4. tr. Recibir o aceptar de cualquier modo que sea.
> 5. tr. Comer o beber. *Tomar un desayuno, el chocolate.* U. t. c. prnl.
> 6. tr. Recibir en sí los efectos de algo, consintiéndolos o padeciéndolos. *Tomar frío, calor, pesadumbre.*
> 7. tr. Elegir, entre varias cosas que se ofrecen al arbitrio, alguna de ellas.
>
> ***toma***
>
> 1. interj. coloq. U. para dar a entender la poca novedad o importancia de algo.
> 2. interj. coloq. U. para señalar como castigo, expiación o desengaño aquello de que se habla. *¿No te dije que corrías peligro? Pues ¡toma!*
>
> ***tómate esa***
>
> 1. expr. coloq. U. cuando a alguien se le da un golpe, o se hace con él otra cosa que sienta, para denotar que la merecía o el acierto del que la ejecuta. Suele añadirse: *y vuelve por otra*.

---

Te recomiendo también que en tus búsquedas utilices siempre la [página del DLE](https://dle.rae.es), que busca siempre sobre la versión más reciente del diccionario y además se va actualizando cada pocos meses. Tu enlace es a una búsqueda sobre el diccionario de 2001, que puede estar algo desfasado.

Comment: walen, es notable cómo esta entrada del diccionario RAE (incorrectamente) carece de la aceptación de sorpresa, que, como todos sabemos la interjección '¡Toma!', sí tiene