# ¿Es la interjección “toma” equivalente a "vaya"?

Tags: interjecciones

> ¡Toma! Pero si esa es Penélope Cruz.

Me pregunto si tal expresión es similar a la de ***vaya***.

Comment: para mi es una exprecion de sorpresa, como "wow","vaya", "orale", etc.

Comment: Muy relacionado: [¿Origen del uso de “¡Toma!” para celebrar algo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31103/1674)

Answer (score 2):

Sí, es una expresión aquí usada en el mismo sentido, para denotar sorpresa, (igual que lo ocurriría con [*¡vaya!*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=bPkTaY4|bPmU3j2), aunque quizás más enfáticamente diciendo *¡toma!*)

> ¿Sabías que Manolo se casó con una chica alemana y está viviendo allá?

a lo que un amigo —indistintamente— responde

> ¡**Toma**, quién lo hubiera dicho! / ¡**Vaya**, quién lo hubiera dicho!